# Python class - inherit attribute from parent class to toplevel

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter, toplevel, python-class

I am trying to use OOP approach to create class that inherit from Parent class to top-level. I want to get the `self.txtofName` from `Window1` to `Window2` class. But it raises an "AttributeError: type object 'Window1' has no attribute 'txtofName'". Can anyone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from tkinter import ttk

class Window1(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry = ('1600x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master.title('ALVO HOTEL')
        
        # ==========Framing============
        self.ftop = Frame(master, width=1600, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, pady=20)
        self.ftop.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.f1 = Frame(master,width=800,height=700,relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, bd=3)
        self.f1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.f4 = Frame(master, width=100, height=700, relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, padx=20, bd=3)
        self.f4.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="nsew")


        self.labelofName = Label(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Name: ', bg='powder blue', bd=10, anchor=W)
        self.labelofName.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(20, 10))
        self.txtofName = Entry(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtofName.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(20, 10))

        self.btnNext = Button(self.f1, padx=10, pady=8, bd=10, fg='white', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), width=10, text='Next Page', bg='green', command=self.new_window_pop)
        self.btnNext.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)
        
    def new_window_pop(self):
        Window2(Toplevel(self.master))


class Window2(Window1):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry = ('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master.title('User Information and Payment')

        self.ftitle = Frame(master, bd=10, width=1350, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.ftitle2 = Frame(master, bd=10, width=1350, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle2.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3, pady=(0,20))
        self.fbutton = Frame(master, width=1350, height=50, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10, pady=20)
        self.fbutton.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=2)
        self.finfomain = Frame(master, bd=10, width=1350, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE)
        self.finfomain.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

        self.finfo1 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=300, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10)
        self.finfo1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.finfo1a = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo1a.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.finfo2 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=450, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo2.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)

        name = Window1.txtofName.get()
        self.FirstName = StringVar()

        self.lblfirstname = Label(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='powderblue', text='First Name:', padx=2)
        self.lblfirstname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.txtfirstfname = Entry(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.FirstName, bd=3, insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtfirstfname.grid(row=0, column=1)
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:/Code/Cpet5/new.py", line 31, in new_window_pop
    Window2(Toplevel(self.master))
  File "d:/Code/Cpet5/new.py", line 57, in __init__
    name = Window1.txtofName.get()
AttributeError: type object 'Window1' has no attribute 'txtofName'
```

Comment: In you own words, when you write `class Window2(Window1):`, what is the intended purpose of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi james I think that the problem is that that you’re wrong to let the Windows2 class inherit the Windows1 class. I've made some changes like

```
def new_window_pop(self):
        #avoid declaring the class type here
        #Window2(Toplevel(self.master))
        #and pass self because you can thought to self as master...
        Window2(self)
```

and in the windows2 notice that we declare geometry, config, title as self, here self is the new windows, and self.parent is window1

```
#declare class type directly...

class Window2(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    super().__init__()

    #Windows2 recive a parent....
    self.parent = parent
    self.geometry = ('1350x750+0+0')
    self.config(bg='powder blue')
    self.title('User Information and Payment')
```

and above all

```
 #here the reference is wrong
    #name = Window1.txtofName.get()
    #the right reference is self.parent....
    name = self.parent.txtofName.get()
    self.FirstName = StringVar()
    #here, if you need to use the textvariable you must first assign it
    self.FirstName.set(name)
```

here the full story, try it.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from tkinter import ttk

class Window1(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry = ('1600x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master.title('ALVO HOTEL')
        
        # ==========Framing============
        self.ftop = Frame(master, width=1600, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, pady=20)
        self.ftop.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.f1 = Frame(master,width=800,height=700,relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, bd=3)
        self.f1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.f4 = Frame(master, width=100, height=700, relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, padx=20, bd=3)
        self.f4.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="nsew")


        self.labelofName = Label(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Name: ', bg='powder blue', bd=10, anchor=W)
        self.labelofName.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(20, 10))
        self.txtofName = Entry(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtofName.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(20, 10))

        self.btnNext = Button(self.f1, padx=10, pady=8, bd=10, fg='white', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), width=10, text='Next Page', bg='green', command=self.new_window_pop)
        self.btnNext.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)
        
    def new_window_pop(self):
        #avoid declaring the class type here
        #Window2(Toplevel(self.master))
        #and pass self...self = master
        Window2(self)

#declare class type directly...
class Window2(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        #Windows2 recive a parent....
        self.parent = parent
        self.geometry = ('1350x750+0+0')
        self.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.title('User Information and Payment')

        #notice this Frame(self,....
        self.ftitle = Frame(self, bd=10, width=1350, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.ftitle2 = Frame(self, bd=10, width=1350, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle2.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3, pady=(0,20))
        self.fbutton = Frame(self, width=1350, height=50, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10, pady=20)
        self.fbutton.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=2)
        self.finfomain = Frame(self, bd=10, width=1350, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE)
        self.finfomain.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

        self.finfo1 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=300, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10)
        self.finfo1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.finfo1a = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo1a.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.finfo2 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=450, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo2.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)

        #here the reference is wrong
        #name = Window1.txtofName.get()
        #the right reference is self.parent....
        name = self.parent.txtofName.get()
        self.FirstName = StringVar()
        #here, if you need to use the textvariable you must first assign it
        self.FirstName.set(name)

        self.lblfirstname = Label(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='powderblue', text='First Name:', padx=2)
        self.lblfirstname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.txtfirstfname = Entry(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.FirstName, bd=3, insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtfirstfname.grid(row=0, column=1)

        
        
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Follow these steps

Don't do
`app = Window1(root)`
Because you already inherited Window1 in Window2

So, use `super` to initialize in Window2

`super().__init__(master)`

Now you can do anythong for Window1 so,
Assign command for button
`self.btnNext.config(command=self.new_window_pop)`

Now create a method for TopLevel Window:

Here is your full code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
from tkinter import ttk


class Window1(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry = ('1600x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master.title('ALVO HOTEL')

        # ==========Framing============
        self.ftop = Frame(master, width=1600, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, pady=20)
        self.ftop.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.f1 = Frame(master, width=800, height=700, relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, bd=3)
        self.f1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.f4 = Frame(master, width=100, height=700, relief=SUNKEN, bg='powder blue', pady=50, padx=20, bd=3)
        self.f4.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="nsew")

        self.labelofName = Label(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text='Name: ', bg='powder blue', bd=10, anchor=W)
        self.labelofName.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(20, 10))
        self.txtofName = Entry(self.f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtofName.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(20, 10))

        self.btnNext = Button(self.f1, padx=10, pady=8, bd=10, fg='white', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), width=10,
                              text='Next Page', bg='green')
        self.btnNext.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)


class Window2(Window1):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.btnNext.config(command=self.new_window_pop)

    def new_window_pop(self):
        self.master = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.master.geometry = '1350x750+0+0'
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        self.master.title('User Information and Payment')

        self.ftitle = Frame(self.master, bd=10, width=1350, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)
        self.ftitle2 = Frame(self.master, bd=10, width=1350, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.ftitle2.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3, pady=(0, 20))
        self.fbutton = Frame(self.master, width=1350, height=50, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10, pady=20)
        self.fbutton.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=2)
        self.finfomain = Frame(self.master, bd=10, width=1350, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE)
        self.finfomain.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

        self.finfo1 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=300, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=10)
        self.finfo1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.finfo1a = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=900, height=100, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo1a.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.finfo2 = Frame(self.finfomain, bd=5, width=450, height=400, bg='powder blue', relief=RIDGE, padx=20)
        self.finfo2.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2)

        name = self.txtofName.get()
        self.FirstName = StringVar()

        self.lblfirstname = Label(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), bg='powderblue', text='First Name:', padx=2)
        self.lblfirstname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.txtfirstfname = Entry(self.finfo1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), textvariable=self.FirstName, bd=3,
                                   insertwidth=5, bg='white', justify='left')
        self.txtfirstfname.grid(row=0, column=1)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window2(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### If you need any explanation ask in comment.